# Change web-API registration field from Email to PhoneNumber

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, owin

I am trying to customize the registration process of Asp.Net Identity(In web-API project).
Is it possible to register a new user with PhoneNumber instead of Email with web-API?

Also, the rest of the features of the Identity framework should work with this new approach?

Which challenges would a programmer face with this approach?

Tried changing Email to PhoneNumber in RegisterBindingModel.cs as:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Mobile number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

The original code was:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email{ get; set; }
```

Changes Made in AccountController.cs

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.PhoneNumber, PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

The expected result is A new user register with just PhoneNumber.

The actual result is, 
Error - "Email cannot be null or empty" which is coming from ModelState.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `User.RequireUniqueEmail` property in `services.AddIdentity` to `false`? I assumed this is an _asp.net core_ project.

Comment: @bolkay, it's a .net framework web-API project.

Answer (score 0):

The following code change in **IdentityConfig.cs** worked:

```
RequireUniqueEmail = false
```

And, Identity framework is also checking for duplicate entries with the error:

"*Name 9xxxxxxx8x is already taken*"

Credit to: @Rudy
[Asp.Net Identity save user without email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905245/asp-net-identity-save-user-without-email)